# POMs catalysis of benzyl alcohol oxidation, why Ni is the best cation with POM for that catalysis?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metal

Why is nickel the optimal cation for benzyl alcohol oxidation with POMs and hydrogen peroxide?

In this article ([Chinese Journal of Chemistry, Volume 30, Issue 2, 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/cjoc.201100144)), they came to a conclusion that Ni gives better conversion then the other metals (Zn, Co, Mn, Cu, Fe) when they used it with Keggin type POM $\ce{Ni3(PW12O40)2}$. See the next note about the active structure:

[image: its the active structure]

How would you prove that Nickel is the best?

[image: the table from the article describes the catalytic activity]

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! Take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) using LaTeX syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Do you know that the three results columns are probably %conversion (of starting material,  to be clear) ,  %selectivity and %yield?  The table should then be self explanatory